# Regex for multi-line data in MySQL column

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a column which has XML in it and I want to use regex to list ids based on a condition.

Part of my XML data which copied to outfile :

```
  <definitions>^M\
    <definition id=
```

I want to list a column based on the xmldata which has `<definitions>` followed by `<definition id="1"`

So far I have tried different combinations of regex but no success

`where <col> REGEXP '.*<definitions>\r.\s+<definition id="1"'`

Comment: Is it MySQL 8 or earlier? Try `where col REGEXP '<definitions>[[:space:]]+<definition id="1"'`. If the whitespace can be missing, replace `+` with `*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `REGEXP` can match anywhere inside a string, not necessarily at the start (unlike `LIKE`), thus you need no `.*` at the start.

MySQL versions before 8.x did not support Perl-like shorthand classes, and `\s` is invalid there. In MySQL 8.x, the ICU regex library supports `\s`.

You may use in any MySQL:

```
where col REGEXP '<definitions>[[:space:]]+<definition id="1"'
```

Or, if the whitespace can be missing between the elements:

```
where col REGEXP '<definitions>[[:space:]]*<definition id="1"'
```

The `[[:space:]]` bracket expression containing `[:space:]` POSIX character class matches any whitespace chars, and `+` mathces 1 or more repetitions of the chars while `*` matches 0 or more of them.